# Android: How to make a scroll-able list of fragments

Tags: java, android

I have several unique `fragments` and I want to be able to scroll between them. Only problem is I want to turn them on and off (and change their order) depending on user preference.

I have already got an `ArrayList` of strings which I can then use to find which `fragments` need to be loaded and which order.

My problem is that from my research there is no way to make a `recycler adapter` or `scrollable view` that accepts `fragments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I found best if you want a smooth scroll between the list of fragments (that means you don't want a view pager). It's got a fair bit of jank but it worked fine in my case.

I had enough `framelayouts` to cover as many `fragments` as I'd ever need. I then set them to the fragments I needed.

```java
private void LoadFragments() {
        mainActiveTools = loadActiveTools();
        frameLayouts = loadFrameLayouts();
        fragments = loadFragments();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        int i = 0;
        while(i != frameLayouts.size()) {
            int currentFrame = frameLayouts.get(i);
            try {
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment currentFrag = fragments.get(i);
                transaction.replace(currentFrame, currentFrag);
                findViewById(currentFrame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                findViewById(currentFrame).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            i++;
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

This code attempts to fill out each of my 5 `framelayouts` stored in said `ArrayList`. A `transaction` is instantiated, and then a `while loop` gives each of the `framelayouts` a `fragment`. Additionally, each `framelayout` is also explicitly told whether or not to be `visible`.

Now I'm a Java/Android programming beginner, but at least for me, this did the job. No idea how scalable this is (my guess would be until you get bored of copy-pasting or the app crashes) nor how performance heavy this is NOR whether or not it will even work for you!

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager). Consider taking a look at this documentation:

- [Slide between fragments using ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)
- [Creating swipe views with tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Think I used one of these and from memory it only displays one fragment and when scrolled it jumps instantly to the next one correct? 

I tried using that but I want to have multiple fragments on screen (however many fit) and to smoothly scroll to the next few as you go down.

Is this even possible? My tutor didn't say it wasn't but also didn't say how.